# None in python array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, boolean

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
n=len(arr)
temp = n*[None]
flag = True
flag= bool(1-flag)
```

I'm new to python, so not sure what it really means.
I want to know what all three lines of code do. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The first line will create an array of five elements

```
    print (arr)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The second will make a variable named 'n' that will contain the number of elements in your array

```
print(n) 
5
```

The third line will create an array with a length of 5 that will only contain None.

None is used to define a variable so that it resets to a variable with no value. It is not similar to a NULL or an empty string, None is an object.

```
 print(temp)
 [None, None, None, None, None]
```

The last line will change your flag value to false.
In standard binary conventions, True is equal to 1 and False is equal to 0. By subtracting a 1 with the flag value that is True, you are doing 1-1 which is equal to Zero. With bool(), you obtain a false.

```
  print(flag)
    False
```